# jQuery Hover SlideToggle 2 Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

OK so i have this small script

```
$( ".checkout, .shoppingCart" ).hover(function() {
  $( ".cartView" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
  });
});
```

That shows the current cart when you hover over 2 li elements .checkout and .shoppingcart

But when you you hover over .shoppingcart and then move over to .checkout it closes and reopens the cart view. Is there a way to prevent this? Kinda like stop it mid-animation and slide back down instead of finishing the slide up then back down.

At the request of someone below here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yBz47/
It isnt pretty but it still shows my issue

Comment: I will put one together give me a few minutes

Comment: @jp310 I added one above

Answer (score 0):

I dont Know if u want this but i just put `shoppingCart` and `checkout` inside a div to hover at same time!

When you move from shoppingCart to checkout because they are at same div the panel dont close!

Just see [hover](http://jsfiddle.net/rm596/yBz47/3/)!

Comment: I had actually tried that with a span (not a div) and it didn't do the trick i thought for sure it would, but no dice i will have to try the div idea but a div might mess up my UL

Comment: @Travis the only way you can achieve this is using similar idea! I will be happy if you accept my anwser